# Monero GUI: unable to sync

Tags: monerod, error-log, peer-discovery

I'm unable to sync, getting the following errror :

```
2017-Mar-17 13:28:54.264211 [P2P9]Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds
```

Comment: I have the same issue using Ubuntu and the CLI monerod. It keeps trying to connect to 213.167.231.2 and fails.

Comment: Someone on reddit suggested to run the following command and it worked: monerod --add-priority-node 38.135.33.74

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the seed nodes at the moment.
This is fixed in the coming release, hopefully in the next day or two: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1879

In the meantime, you can supply a node to start from:
`./monerod --add-peer 107.152.130.98:18080 --add-peer 212.83.175.67:18080 --add-peer 5.9.100.248:18080`
(this is simply adding the first three fallback peers to the command line)